Could a solar farm work at night?
So I'm finding different numbers online, but it seems that the consensus is that solar panels can generate around 0.2-0.3% of their rated power from moonlight, assuming good conditions (clear night, full moon, etc.)
Now for a residential application, this results in a negligible amount of power. The average installation in the US seems to be 8kW, so 0.25% of that translates to 20W. You could maybe run a couple of night lamps from that, although in practice most residential solar systems simply shut down under a certain input.
However, utility scale is a different story. It's again surprisingly hard to ascertain which is the current largest solar farm in the world, but it looks like it might be the Xinjiang facility in China, with an installed capacity of 5 GW. Going again by our 0.25% moonlight efficiency figure, that nets us 12.5MW of power under a clear full moon. That's not nothing. In fact, that's more than most utility projects in the US, which tend to be under 5MW.
So the question is: do these large utility installations keep producing power at night, sky conditions permitting? Why or why not?


It is not worth the effort; there is nothing to be gained, only losses.

There is no reason why a solar farm could or could not work at night in theory. Whether any does work at night must be verified from a source.

From casual googling, it looks like solar Inverters are ~95% efficient. Even if only 10% of the losses are fixed (do not scale with current), then this is a losing proposition. It may be possible to reconfigure the panels into a "nighttime" setup where they all share an inverter or something but I think the economies are just not there.

Whilst the numbers are not there, there are more-or-less serious proposals to have large area man-made reflectors in space that would direct light selectively to solar farms. Russia experimented with this in the 1990s.

I'm aware of solar plants that instead of photo-voltaics use mirrors to reflect light onto a water reservoir to act as a energy store. I suspect this is far more practical than trying to collect energy off the moon (which even in ideal circumstances will only apply for a few days each month).

Dim sun (not the Chinese food delicacies) powers the mars rovers.


The usual PV inverter consists of one or several boost MPPTs, feeding a HV DC bus, feeding a bridge inverter, then a LCL filter, then to the grid. (image link)
PV panels do produce power from moonlight (and even streetlights).
However, when the inverter is operating, the output bridge will be switching. This is unavoidable: to inject power into the grid it must output a sinewave voltage synchronized with the grid voltage. This switching creates a triangular ripple current in the output inductor and filter, just like the inductor current in a buck converter. So when the inverter is synchronized to the grid and operating, there are switching and conduction losses even if it is not injecting any power.
For home inverters (<10kW) these losses seem to be about 0.5%-1% of rated power. Even if higher power and higher voltage inverters tend to be more efficient, losses will never be zero.
The point is, if the inverter is designed for optimum efficiency during the day, at a significant fraction of its rated power, it's going to use devices optimized for that, so its idle losses are likely to exceed the power that would be available from moonlight (0.2% from your question).
To be efficient at very low power, you'd need another inverter in parallel, optimized for low power: using smaller lower capacitance devices, different LC filter values etc. It makes no sense to spend more on this for such a tiny return on investment.
Basically: The idle power consumption of a grid tied inverter cannot be brought down to an arbitrary low value, because it needs to switch all the time to output a sine voltage from PWM. The high power devices cannot sleep to save power.
However, the idle power consumption of DC-DC converters can be minimized down to extremely low values, because they can do sleep-burst cycles. So, if you replace the inverter with a MPPT battery charger, then it's possible in theory to run it on moonlight: the panels can trickle charge the input capacitors, then once in a while the DC-DC converter can wake up and do a burst. However this will only work if the manufacturer took great care to optimize the design for low idle power and counted every bit of milliwatt.
On my previous 3kWp installation, moonlight did generate enough power to charge the DC bus caps, and the caps stored enough to turn the inverter on, boot, send a TCP/IP message to the monitoring server saying it's on, then run out of juice and shut down.
On my new 12kWp installation, when there is snow on the panels, they still produce enough for the inverters to start up... but these inverters are a bit dumber than the previous ones: they don't realize the panels produce less than their idle power use, so they remain online and draw power from the grid then burn it in losses...

Thanks for the detailed answer! That's about what I expected yes, that there could be other part of the system where this wouldn't scale. I thought the economic might be able to work out because (in a heavily solar power mix at least) power generation would be low at night, and this would avoid the need to use batteries and their conversion losses, but I guess that doesn't really work.

On my previous 3kWp installation, moonlight did generate enough power to charge the DC bus caps, and the caps stored enough to turn the inverter on, boot, send a TCP/IP message to the monitoring server saying it's on, then run out of juice and shut down.

Can't the DC power be used directly (locally in some non-grid application) without conversion into AC? For instance charging batteries?

@BuckThorn yes of course, I was talking about a battery charger at the end of the answer. That's different hardware from a grid tied inverter.

Duh, got lost in the preceding conclusion about the inverter and missed that bit.

What a great idea: power the solar panels with streetlights that are powered by the solar panels.   Free zero point energy with no moving parts like the device that has been touted on the internet.

@richard1941 why stop there? Add some mirrors and get infinite energy! But seriously, powering a toy by shining a flashlight or a garden fountain by a floodlight sound like valid use cases.

No, 0.25% moonlight/sunlight is bogus.
Moonlight (full): 0.25 lux
Sunlight: 110000 lux
0.25/110000 = 0.00023 %
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28illuminance%29

We run DC systems that are around 99% efficient, and turn off at night to prevent reverse leakage. Flood lights defeat the system, and require recalibration of the 'off' system, but moonlight doesn't even do that.
